# Passing dates from SQL to ssrs

Tags: sql, date, ssrs-2008

I have a query which I have worked out the week beginning in my SQL which works perfect , this stamps as every Monday.

But when I put this into ssrs it knocks a day off and stamps it as Sunday.

Has anybody come across this before.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a day to date field or parameter expression by using the DateAdd function, similiar to the one in T-SQL.

=DateAdd("d", 1, Fields!your_date)

=DateAdd("d", 1, Parameters!your_date)

If it's a field in a tablix, right click on the field, to get the Expression editor. If it's a parameter, you can right click, properties, specifiy a value, then click on the expressions button to pull up the expressions window. Once in the expressions window, you can expand the common functions window on the left to see the date functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your statement by replacing the dates (in this example MyDateColumn) by adding -1 days:

```
DATEADD(dd, - 1, CAST(MyDateColumn AS date)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's in SSRS I'm having the issue is there a way to add a day with an expression

Comment: I've changed my answer. Please check if it solves your problem.